# How to install the product_images_olbs module in OpenERP 6?

Tags: installation, erp, odoo

I get the error "No references to product.group_product_manager" when I try to install the module product_images_olbs.

I have an OpenERP V 6.0.2 instance running on Ubuntu 10.04. But it seems I run into a documented error. This error shows up in the client (running on windows) when I want to install some modules:

```
Environment Information : 
System : Windows-2003Server-5.2.3790-SP2
OS Name : nt
Operating System Release : 2003Server
Operating System Version : 5.2.3790
Operating System Architecture : 32bit
Operating System Locale : de_DE.cp1252
Python Version : 2.5.2
OpenERP-Client Version : 6.0.2
Last revision No. & ID :Bazaar Package not Found !Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/openerp-server/netsvc.py", line 489, in dispatch
    result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, auth, params)
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/openerp-server/service/web_services.py", line 599, in dispatch
    res = fn(db, uid, *params)
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/openerp-server/osv/osv.py", line 122, in wrapper
    return f(self, dbname, *args, **kwargs)

  (...)

  File "/usr/share/pyshared/openerp-server/osv/orm.py", line 732, in _get_id
    record_id = ir_model_data_obj._get_id(cr, uid, module, xml_id)
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/openerp-server/tools/misc.py", line 823, in cached_result
    result2 = fn(self2, cr, *args[:self.skiparg-2], **kwargs2)
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/openerp-server/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 602, in _get_id
    raise ValueError('No references to %s.%s' % (module, xml_id))
ValueError: No references to product.group_product_manager
```

I was trying to install the product_images_olbs module 6.0.0.1

After some research I found 2 bugreports that seem to fit:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/magentoerpconnect/+bug/695516

https://bugs.launchpad.net/openobject-addons/+bug/695084

---

Edit: The solution in this case was actually that I have to use the latest version of product_images_olbs.

I thought I was using it but this was not the case, and this was caused by my wrong usage of bazaar. (I come from git but getting used to bazaar more and more ;)

And the accepted answer is correct if applied to the old version of the module.

---

This is the new version of \addons\product_images_olbs\security\ir.model.access.csv (from revision 5486):

```
"id","name","model_id:id","group_id:id","perm_read","perm_write","perm_create","perm_unlink"
"access_product_images_olbs_product_images","product_images_olbs_product_images","model_product_images","base.group_sale_manager",1,1,1,1
```

An old version of the same file:

```
"id","name","model_id:id","group_id:id","perm_read","perm_write","perm_create","perm_unlink"
"access_product_images_olbs_product_images","product_images_olbs_product_images","model_product_images","product.group_product_manager",1,1,1,1
```

The old file has references to product.group_product_manager, which is no longer correct for OpenERP 6.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My memory's a bit hazy, but I think that error means that one of the XML files in the module you are trying to install has a reference to a record in the `product` module with id `group_product_manager`, but the `product` module doesn't contain any record with that id.

Do any of the bugs you found have patches or merge proposals? If so, do they help?

One possible solution is to look in the product module and see if that record id was *changed* to something similar and make the same change in the module you're installing.

Another option is to just remove the reference from the module you're installing. Depending on how it's used, that may or may not cause other problems.

Finally, you could create a record with that id for the new module to use. I think all those references get looked up in the `ir_data` table, so you could create a new record there.